# newbie mysql query expecting delimited string

Tags: mysql

here's my data structure:

```
users
id  user
-----------------------
1   foo
2   bar   

rooms_available
id  id_user   name    
----------------------
1   2         room #1 
2   2         room #2 
3   2         room #3
4   2         room #3
```

i would like getting the following result:

```
id_user   user    rooms
-----------------------------
2         bar     1,2,3,4
```

any ideas?
thanks

Comment: checkout mysql `group_concat` function.

Comment: So what about you tried so far? Have you even checked GROUP_CONCAT?

Comment: A good way to get constructive answers is to show in your question what you have tried already and what happens when you do that. Otherwise it looks like you're just asking SO to do your work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `GROUP_CONCAT`. For example:

```
 SELECT users.id as id_user,
        users.name as user,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT rooms_available.id) as rooms
   FROM users
   JOIN rooms_available ON users.id = rooms_available.id_user
```

Comment: What if `rooms_available` has some data from `user id = 1` ?

Comment: Can't we presume there's referential integrity?

Comment: I was referring to `group by` since the aggregate function will return all the data in one row even if you have multiple grouped data. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/153b15/1

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.id as id_user, a.user, b.rooms 
from
    users u
    inner join (select id_user, group_concat(`name`) as rooms from rooms_available group by 1) b on u.id=b.id_user
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.user, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.id ORDER BY b.id)  
FROM users a 
JOIN rooms_available b 
ON a.id = b.id_user
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @SuhailGupta I have just got access to my account again so it looked like I had 1 rep. This DOES answer the question and is almost identical to the one marked as the answer. You didn't leave this comment on any of the other answers, just on the one where you though the user had 1 rep. It is not fair to treat the answer of a low rep differently to the answer of a high rep user. Loose the bias.